# Django Not showing Static Images but shows its alternative text(alt) by displaying["GET /static/image/down.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1771] in console window

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-static

I just simply want to show my static image in template.
I have looked every possible ways to solve this issue and try various approaches but could not get my static images in template. The alternative text of the respective image is shown but image itself not loaded and get this in terminal Window

```
"GET /static/image/down.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1771
```

here how my Django project is laid out is given below
[project files hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2d3q.jpg)

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from myapp import views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
.......]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
MEDIA_URL= "/media/"
```

in template question.html

i have tried different approaches to access the image[with {% load static %} tag on the top of html page]
like

```
<img src="{% static 'image/down.jpg' %}">   
<img style="width: 245px; height: 247px;"
                                    alt="Image description"
                                    src="{% static 'image/down.jpg' %}"/>
<img src="/static/image/up.jpg" alt="Second-image" />
```

but could not get the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pillow installed correctly and if it still wont work, try reinstalling pillow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run: python manage.py collectstatic?

If not work, try:

```
{% load staticfiles i18n %}
```

In addition check django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS